# MATLAB: ceate a x b matrix (or 2D array) from 2 1Darrays, and populate each cell from another array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, populate

I am using MATLAB.

So I have 3 arrays; say a,b,c. a and b represent distances, and c represents a variable with a specific value at the point (a,b).

I have been trying to create a matrix which comprises of (b x a) cells, and the populate it with the values of c, in order to then image, heatmap it etc.

However the issue I have having is that there are many repeating values of a and b; a stays fixed and it then iterates across all values of b, then moves onto the next value of a, and so forth. The range of a and b is fixed and always iterate across equally spaced values though.

Below is the code I have created for this. So for it seems to not to work and I am out of ideas.

```
z_true_len = length(unique(a)); %number of z distances
r_true_len = length(unique(b)); %number of r disatances
data_matrix = zeros(r_true_len,z_true_len); %create r x z matrix, full of 0s
z_past = 0; 
r_past = 0;
z_count = 1;
r_count = 1;
for count = 1: length(a)
    z_current = a(count);
    if z_past ~= z_current
        data_matrix(1:z_count) = c(count);
        z_past = z_current;
        z_count = z_count + 1;
        r_count = 1;
    else
        data_matrix(r_count:z_count) = c(count);
        r_count = r_count + 1;
    end      
end    

data_matrix
```

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Can you give a small example with inputs and desired output?

Comment: Sure, say;
a=(1 1 1 2 2 2)
b=(1 2 3 1 2 3)
c=(1 2 3 4 5 6)

then it would return data_matrix=(1 4, 2 5, 3 6)

Comment: Please see my answer. I'm assuming you mean `[1 4; 2 5; 3 6]` for `data_matrix`

Answer (score 0):

I included a mapping of the `a` and `b` arrays into a space of integers:

```
% Data
a = [ 0.5 0.5 2.5 0.5 2.5 2.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 2.5 4.5 0.5];
b = [-35 -25 -25 -15 -45 -35 -35 -45 -15 -15 -25 -45];
c = [2 1 -2 4 6 4 6 8 4 1 -5 2];

% Mapping from real to integers
a_unique = sort(unique(a));
b_unique = sort(unique(b));
a_idx = zeros(size(a));
b_idx = zeros(size(b));
for ii = 1:numel(a_unique),
    a_idx(a_unique(ii)==a) = ii;
end
for ii = 1:numel(b_unique),
    b_idx(b_unique(ii)==b) = ii;
end

% Create matrix
data_matrix = zeros(numel(b_unique),numel(a_unique));
for count = 1:length(a_idx),
    data_matrix(b_idx(count),a_idx(count)) = c(count);    
end  

% Plot
figure;
imagesc(data_matrix);
```

Comment: no unfortuanetely all of a,b and c dont comprise of just integers. I get "Attempted to access data_matrix(0.005,-0.09833); index must be a positive integer or logical." as an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to define `data_matrix` with the appropriate dimensions, and then fill values in using [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.es/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) (see [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)):

```
m = max(b); %// number of rows in result
n = max(a); %// number of columns in result
data_matrix = NaN(m,n); %// define result matrix with appropriate dimensions
data_matrix(sub2ind([m n], b, a)) = c; %// fill values using indexing
```

If `a` and `b` don't always contain integers: first transform into "integer labels" with the third output of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), and then proceed as above:

```
[~, ~,  bb] = unique(b); %// get integer labels for b
[~, ~,  aa] = unique(a); %// get integer labels for a
m = max(bb); %// number of rows in result
n = max(aa); %// number of columns in result
data_matrix = NaN(m,n); %// define result matrix with appropriate dimensions
data_matrix(sub2ind([m n], bb, aa)) = c; %// fill values using indexing
```